# SQL Server : foreign key references invalid table

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm getting a foreign key references invalid table message telling me that `dbo.ValueStream` is an invalid table.

**Edit**: I originally posted my code in the incorrect order. Fixed in the edit to reflect the order it was done in SSMS

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ValueStream 
(
    ValueStreamKey int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_ValueStream_ValueStreamKey PRIMARY KEY,
    ValueStream nvarchar(20),
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.NonConformance 
(
    NonConformanceKey int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_NonConformance_NonConformanceKey PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerVendorKey int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_NonConformance_CustomerVendorKey_CustomerVendor_CustomerVendorKey
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.CustomerVendor(CustomerVendorKey),
    ValueStreamKey int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_NonConformance_ValueStream_Key_ValueStream_ValueStreamKey
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.ValueStream(ValueStreamKey),
    RepairOrder nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    WorkOrder nvarchar(8) NOT NULL,
    PartNumber nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SerialNumber nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PartDescription nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InductionDate datetime NOT NULL,
    TriageStartDate datetime NOT NULL,
    TriageCompletionDate datetime NOT NULL,
    RequiresRRCA Bit NOT NULL,
    NonConformanceSummary nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Your sequence of table creation is wrong. move create table script dbo.ValueStream  above dbo.NonConformance and place GO in between the. it will work.

Comment: I ran your revised script successfully, after commenting out the `FK_NonConformance_CustomerVendorKey_CustomerVendor_CustomerVendorKey` foreign key constraint since you didn't include the referenced table in your script.

Comment: If the invalid table message is an Intellisense error, refresh the cache with CTRL+SHIFT+R.

Comment: This code is now running without any error.

Comment: refresh the cache with CTRL+SHIFT+R removed the error indication. Thanks, I'll have to remember this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking out the CONSTRAINT FK_NonConformance_CustomerVendorKey_CustomerVendor_CustomerVendorKey
FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.CustomerVendor(CustomerVendorKey)
(we don't have that one)
and running the scripts seperately - first the first table and then the creation of the referencing table - this works for me.
No code errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `dbo.NonConformance` first in the script that you have posted. You need to move the `CREATE TABLE dbo.ValueStream` statement so that it is created first, ensuring there is a `GO` statement still between the two `CREATE TABLE` statements.

As it stands you are trying to create a foreign key to a table that does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I goofed on posting the code here. I ran the CREATE TABLE script for dbo.Value Stream first. I then populated some data into dbo.ValueStream. After that I ran the CREATE TABLE script for dbo.NonConformance. The scrip executed without issue. If I try save a record to dbo.NonConformance with a valid ValueStreamKey I'm permitted to do so. If I try to save a record with an invalid ValueStreaKey I get an error, as would be expected. The two tables seem to be working correctly, I'm just having trouble understanding why the Invalid Table message is there.